# "What" was expanding during the Inflationary epoch?

Tags: special-relativity, space-expansion, big-bang, cosmological-inflation, space

I know, space. But in my opinoin, space makes only sense if there is something that experience things like position and distance. A universe without anything that require position and distance to other objects is spaceless. Also, spacetime is a mathematicle construct to explain certain phenomena, eg. the increasing distance between two objects as result of "spacetime" being a "real" thing that it expanding. But in reallity there are just distant objects moving away from each other.

Anyways, according to modern inflation theorys there was nothing during inflation. And if there was something, it would be diluted to nothing. Everything came from the "stopping" of inflation, transforming its energy to everything that exist now. So from my view, its only at this moment that space come into existence and began to slowly distribude its enegery contents (like particles) across spacetime

Comment: What do you mean when you say that spacetime is a "mathematical construct"?

Answer (score 2):

You are bordering on an interesting philosophical point of view called [Mach's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle), which states that inertial frames of reference are determined by the matter content of the Universe. In the absence of matter, there is no way to establish what is truly meant by an inertial frame. You aren't interested in inertial frames, per se, in your question, but I take it you are making a similar point about length; the notion of length only makes sense if you have matter to measure that length.

Mach's principle has had mixed successes. On philosophical grounds I don't know if I have a good answer to the question of whether space makes sense without matter.

Fortunately, we don't have to answer such a difficult philosophical question in inflation, and simple need to answer a physics question. There *is* matter/energy density during inflation. The inflaton (the field that drives inflation) provides energy density. This energy density is associated with a length scale. You can think of the length scale as the size of a cube you would need for space to contain, say, $1$ joule of energy. When you add in gravity, you can also consider the length scale of the *horizon*, or the distance beyond which you cannot receive information in an exponentially expanding universe.

You can make this more visceral by considering small fluctuations in the inflaton field (for example due to quantum effects). These small fluctuations "freeze out" when they get expanded outside the horizon. In the inflationary paradigm, these frozen out perturbations become the seeds of structure in the universe when they "re-enter" the horizon after inflation ends.

Comment: Mach's principle stems from the early 1890s. Modern physics demonstrated that its assumption that there can be an empty universe is false. That's pretty much the end of that line of reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

The inflaton field was present during inflation. It, and any fluctuations within it, was expanding.

You are right to think that if the universe is empty, then there is no objective sense in which it can expand. (For example, the expanding [Milne universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milne_model) is equivalent to the static Minkowski spacetime.)

Comment: The universe is not empty. Do we get false results by oversimplifying theory too much? Absolutely.